# Is it possible to cut off the beginning of a string using regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string which contains a path, such as

```
/foo/bar/baz/hello/world/bla.html
```

Now, I'd like to get everything from the second-last `/`, i.e. the result shall be

```
/world/bla.html
```

Is this possible using a regex? If so, how?

My current solution is to `split` the string into an array, and join its last two members again, but I'm sure that there is a better solution than this.

Comment: Will it always be a fixed "last two"? Or are you always going to ignore "/foo/bar/baz/hello" portion?

Comment: is using Regex mandatory or it is just for the fancy Regex can bring?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with `split` and `join`, I don't know why people always need a regex!

Comment: I think your solution is the better one. It's a very cheap operation and I can see how to do that with a very readable, two or three LOC code. Using regex will save you, like, half a nanossecond every time you do that? And it'll make the code harder to read. If you wanted to extrapolate from that to a more complex problem, where scalability is a concern, then I'd go for something else.

Comment: It will always be a fixed "last two". And using a regex was just another idea that came to my mind, which seemed more simple then splitting and joining again.

Comment: @GoloRoden There are 5 answers, and probably all of them are correct. Why don't you accept one ?

Comment: Because I can't decide which one to accept, as they are all good, right and helpful. It wouldn't be fair to prefer one over the other, as none is significantly better than the rest. And I can't accept all of them :-/

Answer (score 3):

For example:

```
> '/foo/bar/baz/hello/world/bla.html'.replace(/.*(\/.*\/.*)/, "$1")
/world/bla.html
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also do

```
str.split(/(?=\/)/g).slice(-2).join('')
```

Comment: Nice one-liner!  The OP said he's already using `split` and `join`, but I bet he's not using them like this!

Answer (score 2):

```
> '/foo/bar/baz/hello/world/bla.html'.match(/(?:\/[^/]+){2}$/)[0]
"/world/bla.html"
```

Without regular expression:

```
> var s = '/foo/bar/baz/hello/world/bla.html';
> s.substr(s.lastIndexOf('/', s.lastIndexOf('/')-1))
"/world/bla.html"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work:

```
var str = "/foo/bar/baz/hello/world/bla.html";
alert( str.replace( /^.*?(\/[^/]*(?:\/[^/]*)?)$/, "$1") );
```

This will allow for there being possibly only one last part (like, "foo/bar").

Comment: You could use Fiddle to remove the "I think" part of your answer, no?

Comment: @Renan well I did try it in my console, I confess :)

Comment: You need to escape *all* of the slashes.  Unlike normal metacharacters, the regex delimiter doesn't lose its special meaning when it appears in a character class.

Comment: So it does!  [Ideone](http://ideone.com/) flagged that as a syntax error, but when I went back just now and told it to run the code anyway, it worked.  Pshaw!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `/(\/[^\/]*){2}$/` which selects a slash and some content twice followed by the end of the string.

See this [regexplained](http://tinyurl.com/ngqaux7).